# NodeJS error events.js:182 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Tags: javascript, node.js

Problems with the server NodeJS installed npm package nodemon tried everything, nothing works error events.js:182
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

```js
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('Responding to a request.');
  res.end('<h1>Hello, World!</h1>');
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: EADDRINUSE = Error, Address in Use. Port 3000 is already in use man. How about 8000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run netstat -abno as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) to figure out what process is bound to port 3000 and kill it using the task manager or by using Taskkill in cmd

Failing that you can call `server.listen(8080)` or some other port number besides 3000

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to just restart my computer